# How to see all HTTP Get request sent from browser without debugging tool?

Tags: ajax, get, httprequest, browser-history

so, I have page doing a number of ajax and jsonp(i.e.  injection) to get data.  I would like to know how to find out the request URL I have made without using debugging tools, like firebug. etc.   i.e. the history of GET request of the browser. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the most part, browsers do NOT log a history of their HTTP GET requests.  Also, if you're using ajax, you're probably doing HTTP POST requests as well.

You don't have to use an in-browser tool like Firebug, but you will need some tool to actually get a history of requests and the request bodies.

You can use a tool like [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which is a proxy that gets all HTTP traffic outgoing from your computer (including from your browser and all other applications).

If you have control of the server environment, you can also set up logging on the server to capture this data.

Comment: My purpose is to just look into client side browser without using any plugin tool.  also, I wonder if the url & query used in JSONP (<script>) will be logged.   I tried Google Chrome: Chrome://history   but I don't see any url history from either ajax or jsonp call.   I would like to confirm and i want to know how to see the detail history in all browsers. :)

Comment: To my knowledge, modern browsers do not include AJAX requests in the browser history.  The browser history only has the URLs of the pages you've visited (i.e. the URLs that have appeared in your address bar).  You will not be able to get the information you are looking for without using a plugin or external of some sort.

Comment: Fiddler also has a plugin system so you could even customize it if you so desire

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or a similar tool to monitor the network traffic and inspect the packets.